# Dynamically change the URL passed to the YouTube player

Tags: javascript

Dynamically change the URL passed to the YouTube player

YouTube’s player is great but how can we call this object multiple times in our script and pass a new URL to it each time?

For instance, a single copy of the object would sit in our script either hidden or in a container like so:

```
 <div Style="Position:Absolute; Left:430px; Top:30px;";>
 <object width="350" height="25">
 <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/stCKjZniMsQ?autohide=2&autoplay=0&border=0&cc_load_policy=0&controls=2&fs=0&hd=1&iv_load_policy=3&loop=0&modestbranding=1&rel=1&showinfo=1&showsearch=1"
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="350" height="25">
 </embed></object></div>
```

...and then whenever we call it in our script with a nifty function like this it’ll fire up playing the video:

Function CallYouTube(URL) { }

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Reading what Youtube's tech info had to say but nothing relevant found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand so well, but here I go...

You just need to re-set the "src" attribute of your desired element, in this case, your embed element.